# Enabling copy paste feature in a readonly textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a WPF textbox where I have set the `IsReadonly = True`. I want to enable the Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V & Right Click Copy-Paste features for this textbox. Is there any inbuilt functionality within WPF textbox for this?

Comment: Ctrl+C and Right Click Copy already works. As for paste - textbox is read only, so how you suppose paste to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to allow only copy/paste but no other text inputs. Maybe you want to enable the keyboard navigation/selection as well so that the user can navigate around and select some text.

To accomplish that you have to remove the `IsReadOnly = True` and set the following EventHandler:

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown">
```

The code behind then looks like this:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        // Enable copy/paste and selection of all text.
        case Key.C:
        case Key.V:
        case Key.A:
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
                return;
            break;

        // Enable keyboard navigation/selection.
        case Key.Left:
        case Key.Up:
        case Key.Right:
        case Key.Down:
        case Key.PageUp:
        case Key.PageDown:
        case Key.Home:
        case Key.End:
            return;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

To disable the Cut entry in the right click context menu you have to set a custom ContextMenu as well:

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

This should enable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and right click copy/paste features but disable all other inputs.

Comment: This does it! I also added Key.Back and Key.Delete to the case structure.

Answer (score 0):

I haved used custom `ContextMenu` showing `Copy, Paste` commands.

I have handled `ContextMenuOpening / Closing events` to show `ContextMenu`. If we dont handle these events, `ContextMenu` will appear but commands would be disabled.

I have handled `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown` events for `Ctrl+V` paste.

I have set `CaretBrush` to `Transparent`, otherwise it will appear when we set `IsReadOnly = true`.

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown_1" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown_1" ContextMenuOpening="TextBox_ContextMenuOpening_1" ContextMenuClosing="TextBox_ContextMenuClosing_1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="a" CaretBrush="Transparent" Background="Bisque" Width="277">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Handlers :

```
private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening_1(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = false;
}

private void TextBox_ContextMenuClosing_1(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = true;
}   

private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.V && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = false;
    }
}

private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

Please tell if this solves your issue at hand.